# Partial explicit implementation of interface in .NET

Tags: c#

We would like to do a "partial explicit implementation" of a interface in classes that are part of a class library. By partial explicit implementation I mean implementing some members of the interface implicitly and remaining members of same interface explicitly.
Please let us know of the possible concerns we need to look out for.

More specifically supposing we have `IDriver` interface that is defined as follows. The `IDriver` interface defines the fundamental capability of all drivers.

```
interface IDriver
{
    IDriverIdentity DriverIdentity { get; }
    IDriverOperation Operation { get; }
    IDriverUtility Utility { get; }
}

public class MyDriver1 : IDriver
{
    // Implement the first and second member of IDriver implicitly
    public IDriverIdentity DriverIdentity
    {
        get
        {
            // return a IDriverIdentity object that user can use to assess Identity operations...
        }
    }
    public IDriverOperation Operation
    {
        get
        {
            // return a IDriverOperation object that user can use to access DriverOperation related properties and members..
        }
    }
    // Implement the last member of interface explicitly
    IDriverUtility IDriver.Utility
    {
        get
        {
            // return a IDriverUtility object that user can use to access fundamental utility operations that is mandated for every "Driver" object...
        }
    }
    public MyDriver1Utility Utility
    {
        get
        {
            // return MyDriver1Utility object that user can use to access utility operations available in this driver ...
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly let us suppose we have `MyDriver2`, `MyDriver3`, etc that implement the `DriverIdentity` and `Operation` implicitly and `Utility` explicitly.

In all `Driver` classes we would like to implement `DriverIdentity` and `Operation`  implicitly so that a user has a consistent view of `DriverIdentity` and `Operation` while using different `Driver` objects.
However, the `Utility` member we would like to implement explicitly and provide additional utility operations specific to that driver while accessed from the driver object.

We are looking to understand any possible side-effects/consequences of partial explicit implementation in this scenario. Please let us know you comments.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `MyDriver1Utility` should already include all operations of `IDriverUtility`, if the class implements the interface. Why do you need both? And if you do need both, shouldn't you use two properties?

Comment: Good question. I wouldn't think twice about having a mixed implicit/explicit implementation, but I'm interested to hear the answers to this question.

Comment: Biggest one is following the code, from my experience. I inherited a design that relies on this manouver and trying to get your head round what it's doing versus your understanding of the intent is difficult. Don't go loony with it.

Comment: If what your trying to do is hide the concrete implementation of `Driver1Utility` when the object is cast as `IDriver` then I would say your approach is fine. Assuming all your `DriverUtility` classes are using inheritance your explicit implementation would just look like: `get { return (IDriverUtility)Driver1Utility; }`

Answer (score 1):

Sure you need an interface? How about an abstract class (because I think in your case the driver is more of a "type" rather than "behavior").

```
public abstract class Driver
{
    public abstract DriverIdentity Identity { get; }
    public abstract DriverOperation Operation { get; }

    protected abstract DriverUtility Utility { get; }
}
```

If you intend to access "Utility" from outside of a class, then you can add "internal" access modifier (but in this case you should really consider just declaring it "public" as well).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: I have changed the names slightly for confidentiality purpose. IDriver interface is well establilshed in our API and we cannot change that. The IDriver interface defines the behavior of "Drivers" (fundamental capabilities that every "Driver" must possess - in terms of Identity, Operation and Utility)...

Comment: @Raghavendra is it then possible to have a `DriverBase` abstract class where the `Identity` and `Operation` are implemented implicitly and `Utility` - explicitly (having a constructor that takes all three). Or am I totally off the original question already?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use generics, like

```
interface IDriver<TUtillity> where TUtillity : IDriverUtility
{
  IDriverIdentity DriverIdentity { get; }
  IDriverOperation Operation { get; }
  TUtillity Utility { get; }
}
```

You could also consider making the interface *covariant* in `TUtillity`, that is put an "out" in the declaration: `interface IDriver<out TUtillity>`.

Comment: As far as I can tell the OP is trying to *hide* the concrete implementation when the object is cast as `IDriver`, which is why `Utility` is `IDriverUtility`.

Comment: We cannot change the IDriver interface definition since it is well established in our API. All our Drivers must implement IDriver interface.

Comment: We are looking at design of "Driver" classes that implement IDriver. We want to implement Utility explicitly so that we have scope to provide a custom "Utility" in Driver class that implements IDriverUtility that has additional utility operations specific to that driver. When a user says session.Utility all the utility operations in that driver must be available to him in addition to IDriverUtility members. However, for Operation and Identity we decided to implicitly implement so that the user has a consistent view in all Driver objects without anything less/more than the interface members.

Comment: @Raghavendra OK. Then my answer is not very helpful. You aksed about any "possible side-effects/consequences" of implementing some propeties implicitly and others explicitly. I don't think there are any (that you have not already mentioned yourself). Is it correct that `IDriver` is non-public (that is `internal`) while `MyDriver1` is public?